# Anonymous Functions In Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, anonymous-function

What is an analogy used to explain anonymous functions in javascript to a layman person?
I am a 13 year old coder trying to explain anonymous functions to people without knowledge of coding how can I explain anonymous functions without using any big words like **parameters** or **curly braces**

Comment: Why would you need to tell people without knowledge what anonymous functions are? Just tell them you do shit with computer and call it the day.

Comment: anonymous functions are just regular functions without a name

Comment: Functions without a name. Since functions are just objects, they can be used like other objects, and objects don't have to have names either.

Comment: The good old metaphor, a function is like a machine, you put something in it, and it gives you what you need! About the anonymous functions, i think the machine thing should work.

Comment: I don't know but I think that `parameter` is more basic knowledge than an annon func...

Comment: What analogy did you use to explain a named function?

Comment: It is mostly used as a callback function or self invoking function. It is used where that function has to be called only once (since it does not have a name, it cannot be called else where in the code).

Comment: @kinakuta I guess "object" is even bigger word than "curly brace" or "parameter" ; ).

Comment: If someone needs to understand anonymous functions in javascript, they're going to need to understand objects too. One thing might need to precede the other.

Comment: Anonymous function are like one night stands. Once the work is done, you will never hear of them again. If they are not a 1 night stand, you will still be able to call them. Oh wait, you're 13... That may not be the best analogy...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anonymous functions are just functions without names. Functions are things that actually do something (they perform a job).

So the analogy could be that there are people that do jobs at a store. Regular functions are people that do their job while wearing a name tag. Anonymous functions are the guys who work at a store that don't have name tags.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

**Anonymous** functions are functions that are dynamically declared at runtime. They’re called anonymous functions because they aren’t given a name in the same way as normal functions.

Anonymous functions are declared using the function operator instead of the function declaration. You can use the function operator to create a new function wherever it’s valid to put an expression. For example you could declare a new function as a parameter to a function call or to assign a property of another object.

Here’s a typical example of a named function:

```
function flyToTheMoon()
{
  alert("Zoom! Zoom! Zoom!");
}
flyToTheMoon();
```

Refer - [Link](http://helephant.com/2008/08/23/javascript-anonymous-functions/)